# Passing variable to another view controller using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, storyboard

**.m file from which I'm trying to set the `message` variable:**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SingleMessageViewController* vc = (SingleMessageViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SingleMessageViewController"];
    vc.message = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

**.h file of the view controller I'm instantiating:**

```
@interface SingleMessageViewController : POSCommonViewController
{
    NSString *message;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *message;
@end
```

**.m file of the view controller I'm instantiating (`viewDidLoad` method only):**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.message);
}
```

`NSLog` in the last file quoted returns nil (view loads without any problems). I've tried changing the properties, etc. - nothing worked for me. What could be the problem here?

Comment: have you synthesize message variable?

Comment: Have you checked [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text; is returning the right value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `textLabel` property of the selected cell could be nil. Use an intermediate string  variable to get the cell's text and then set the message to that. It'll make it easier to see the message when you step through the first method in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks, it was a mistake in other parts of the class and the property was set to `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

No its not work .You are creating the object of the controller inside the first controller and setting the property for that particular object . Then how you can access this inside the new controllers object ?  To achieve this you can use the following ways:

1.you can override the init method in the second  view controller that is `initWithMessage:(NSString *)message`

2.You can add the property inside the appDelegate class. That will be shared through the application .

3.But best way is to make a singleton class if you want to share anything within the classes .

Comment: There's nothing wrong with accessing an object's properties through its accessors as the OP is doing.

Comment: @Caleb:I don't know how ? He is setting the value on  object of the second view controller in first view controller and accessing it on the another object .

Comment: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true];` He is using it in the same object (`vc`). It is perfectly alright.